# SSL Certificate add failed,Cannot create a file when that file already exists

Tags: azure, iis, azure-devops

I have deployed the code to IIS server by using pipelines.
But i got an error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWuFR.png)

Anyone please help me to solve this issue.

when i try to chnage the certificate it is not chnages in the IIS server

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing this error message because there was previously a certificate that was SSL bound to both the IP address and port specified in the SSL binding command. You will first need to run the following command:

```
netsh http delete sslcert ipport=<IPaddress:portNumber>
```

When that command runs successfully, you can run the SSL binding command and it will work.

Comment: Thanks. I have deleted my old binding.